# Riemann mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

### Riemann mapping theorem

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a region and $\mathbb{D}$ be the unit disk, $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$. We define the equivalence relation of the set of the regions in $\mathbb{C}$ as follows:
Two regions $\Omega_1,\Omega_2 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ are conformally equivalent ($\Omega_1 \sim \Omega_2$) when there is $f\in H(\Omega_1)$ ($f$ analytic on $\Omega_1$) with $f:\Omega_1 \rightarrow \Omega_2$ is bijective (one to one).

Then we have: $\Omega \sim \mathbb{D} \Leftrightarrow \Omega$ is simply connected and $\Omega \neq \mathbb{C}$.

My questions revolves around the proof. Can someone describe me in descriptive steps (an outline in words) how the proof works?

Thank you very much for your time and patience, I appreciate it very much!

Comment: The statement is not correct: $\Omega$ is simply connected.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the "not" should not be there!

Comment: Please see Section 3 of the Wikipedia page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem  You might also be interested in the approach via normal families - see, for example, Section 23 of Taylor's on-line notes: http://math.unc.edu/Faculty/met/complex.pdf

Comment: @Chris In your question above the letter $\,\mathbb{D}\,$ has two definitions...

Comment: Where? I defined it as the set of open unit disks.

Comment: @Chris No, you first said it was the set of all open disks, and then a few characters later, it is the *unit disk* (which is probably what you intend, otherwise the $\Omega \sim \mathbb{D}$ doesn't make much sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found following resource:

http://www.dancalloway.com/lets_have_a_word/riemann-mapping-theorem-explained

It's really very good and fitted my needs well.

Comment: the link has died :(